# How to replace multiple strings in a file using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, replace

I am writing a script for customising a configuration file. I want to replace multiple instances of strings within this file, and I tried using PowerShell to do the job.

It works fine for a single replace, but doing multiple replaces is very slow because each time it has to parse the whole file again, and this file is very large. The script looks like this:

```
$original_file = 'path\filename.abc'
$destination_file =  'path\filename.abc.new'
(Get-Content $original_file) | Foreach-Object {
    $_ -replace 'something1', 'something1new'
    } | Set-Content $destination_file
```

I want something like this, but I don't know how to write it:

```
$original_file = 'path\filename.abc'
$destination_file =  'path\filename.abc.new'
(Get-Content $original_file) | Foreach-Object {
    $_ -replace 'something1', 'something1aa'
    $_ -replace 'something2', 'something2bb'
    $_ -replace 'something3', 'something3cc'
    $_ -replace 'something4', 'something4dd'
    $_ -replace 'something5', 'something5dsf'
    $_ -replace 'something6', 'something6dfsfds'
    } | Set-Content $destination_file
```

Answer (score 194, accepted):

One option is to chain the `-replace` operations together. The `` ` `` at the end of each line escapes the newline, causing PowerShell to continue parsing the expression on the next line:

```js
$original_file = 'path\filename.abc'
$destination_file =  'path\filename.abc.new'
(Get-Content $original_file) | Foreach-Object {
    $_ -replace 'something1', 'something1aa' `
       -replace 'something2', 'something2bb' `
       -replace 'something3', 'something3cc' `
       -replace 'something4', 'something4dd' `
       -replace 'something5', 'something5dsf' `
       -replace 'something6', 'something6dfsfds'
    } | Set-Content $destination_file
```

Another option would be to assign an intermediate variable:

```js
$x = $_ -replace 'something1', 'something1aa'
$x = $x -replace 'something2', 'something2bb'
...
$x
```

Comment: Can $original_file == $destination_file?  As in I am modifying the same file as my source?

Comment: Because of the way PowerShell cmdlets stream their input/ouput, I don't believe it would work to write out to the same file in the same pipeline. However, you could do something like `$c = Get-Content $original_file; $c | ... | Set-Content $original_file`.

Comment: Have you problems about file encoding using **Set-Content** that not mantains the original encoding? UTF-8 or ANSI encodings for example.

Comment: Yeah PowerShell is...unhelpful like that. You have to detect encoding yourself, e.g. https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git/blob/869d4c5159797755bc04749db47b166136e59132/install.ps1#L23-L37

Comment: This solution has failed for me. It took a longer time to process and it generated a very big file instead of a file with 30 short lines that is in the existing file.

Answer (score 32):

To get the post by George Howarth working properly with more than one replacement you need to remove the break, assign the output to a variable ($line) and then output the variable:

```
$lookupTable = @{
    'something1' = 'something1aa'
    'something2' = 'something2bb'
    'something3' = 'something3cc'
    'something4' = 'something4dd'
    'something5' = 'something5dsf'
    'something6' = 'something6dfsfds'
}

$original_file = 'path\filename.abc'
$destination_file =  'path\filename.abc.new'

Get-Content -Path $original_file | ForEach-Object {
    $line = $_

    $lookupTable.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
        if ($line -match $_.Key)
        {
            $line = $line -replace $_.Key, $_.Value
        }
    }
   $line
} | Set-Content -Path $destination_file
```

Comment: This is by far the best approach I've seen so far. The only issue is that I had to read the entire file contents to a variable first in order to use the same source/destination file paths.

Comment: this looks like the best answer, though I've seen some weird behavior with it matching incorrectly. i.e. in the case where you have a hash table with hex values as strings (0x0, 0x1, 0x100, 0x10000) and 0x10000 will match 0x1.

Answer (score 20):

With version 3 of PowerShell you can chain the replace calls together:

```
 (Get-Content $sourceFile) | ForEach-Object {
    $_.replace('something1', 'something1').replace('somethingElse1', 'somethingElse2')
 } | Set-Content $destinationFile
```

Comment: Works fine + fluent flavor

Comment: As long as you don't need RegEx

Comment: Where does the question mention regex?

Answer (score 13):

Assuming you can only have one `'something1'` or `'something2'`, etc. per line, you can use a lookup table:

```
$lookupTable = @{
    'something1' = 'something1aa'
    'something2' = 'something2bb'
    'something3' = 'something3cc'
    'something4' = 'something4dd'
    'something5' = 'something5dsf'
    'something6' = 'something6dfsfds'
}

$original_file = 'path\filename.abc'
$destination_file =  'path\filename.abc.new'

Get-Content -Path $original_file | ForEach-Object {
    $line = $_

    $lookupTable.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
        if ($line -match $_.Key)
        {
            $line -replace $_.Key, $_.Value
            break
        }
    }
} | Set-Content -Path $destination_file
```

If you can have more than one of those, just remove the `break` in the `if` statement.

Comment: I see TroyBramley added $line just before the last line to write any line that had no changes in it.  Okay.  In my case I only changed every line needing replacements.

Answer (score 12):

A third option, for a pipelined one-liner is to nest the -replaces:

```
PS> ("ABC" -replace "B","C") -replace "C","D"
ADD
```

And:

```
PS> ("ABC" -replace "C","D") -replace "B","C"
ACD
```

This preserves execution order, is easy to read, and fits neatly into a pipeline.  I prefer to use parentheses for explicit control, self-documentation, etc.  It works without them, but how far do you trust that?

-Replace is a Comparison Operator, which accepts an object and returns a presumably modified object.  This is why you can stack or nest them as shown above.

Please see:

```
help about_operators
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a general reusable solution:

```
function Replace-String {
    [CmdletBinding()][OutputType([string])] param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, ValueFromPipeLine = $True)]$InputObject,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, Position = 0)][Array]$Pair,
        [Alias('CaseSensitive')][switch]$MatchCase
    )
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Pair.get_Count()) {
        if ($Pair[$i] -is [Array]) {
            $InputObject = $InputObject |Replace-String -MatchCase:$MatchCase $Pair[$i++]
        }
        else {
            $Regex = $Pair[$i++]
            $Substitute = if ($i -lt $Pair.get_Count() -and $Pair[$i] -isnot [Array]) { $Pair[$i++] }
            if ($MatchCase) { $InputObject = $InputObject -cReplace $Regex, $Substitute }
            else            { $InputObject = $InputObject -iReplace $Regex, $Substitute }
        }
    }
    $InputObject
}; Set-Alias Replace Replace-String
```

Usage:

```
$lookupTable |Replace 'something1', 'something1aa', 'something2', 'something2bb', 'something3', 'something3cc'
```

or:

```
$lookupTable |Replace ('something1', 'something1aa'), ('something2', 'something2bb'), ('something3', 'something3cc')
```

Example:

```
'hello world' |Replace ('h','H'), ' ', ('w','W')
HelloWorld
```

Comment: I have created a formal PowerShell request for this: [`#15876` Make -Replace operator support multiple Regex/Substitution pairs](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15876)