# Convert the value of a positional parameter into a variable (powershell)

Tags: powershell, scripting

In PowerShell 3 I'm performing a regex replace on a string and I would like to pass the '$1' positional parameter to a function as a variable (see the last line in script.ps1)

My code

testFile.html

```
<%%head.html%%>
<body></body></html>
```

head.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title></title></head>
```

script.ps1

```
$r = [regex]"<\%\%([\w.-_]+)\%\%>" # matches my markup e.g. <%%head.html%%>
$fileContent = Get-Content "testFile.html" | Out-String # test file in which the markup should be replaced
function incl ($fileName) {        
    Get-Content $fileName | Out-String
}
$r.Replace($fileContent, (incl '$1'));
```

The problem is on the last line in script.ps1 which is that I couldn't find a way how to resolve the function call so that Get-Content gets the correct value from $fileName. It sees it as '$1' reading from the error message:

```
Get-Content : Cannot find path 'C:\path\to\my\dir\$1' because it does not exist.
```

I want 'C:\path\to\my\dir\head.html'

Basically, what I want to achieve with this script is that it merges others static HTML pages into my page wherever I specify so with the <%% %%> marks.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
@'
<%%head.html%%>
<body></body></html>
'@ > testFile.html

@'
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title></title></head>
'@ > head.html

$r = [regex]"<\%\%([\w.-_]+)\%\%>"
$fileContent = Get-Content testFile.html -Raw
$matchEval = {param($matchInfo)         
    $fileName = $matchInfo.Groups[1].Value
    Get-Content $fileName -Raw
}
$r.Replace($fileContent, $matchEval)
```

The second parameter is a MatchEvaluator callback which expects one parameter which is of type MatchInfo.  Also, if you're on v3 you don't need to pipe through `Out-String`, you can just use the `-Raw` parameter on `Get-Content`.

BTW there is a way to do this if you have a *function* (not a scriptblock) called matchEval, that is:

```
$r.Replace($fileContent, $function:matchEval)
```

Comment: Thank you Keith, this is what I was looking for. I couldn't figure out the form of a proper callback but now I see it. Thanks.