# Powershell -replace "text pattern" in multiply strings

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

I have a test.lua (UTF-8) file:

```
function private.PostAuctionsThread(self, auctionInfo)
self:SetThreadName("SHOPPING_POST_AUCTIONS")
local auctionRecord = auctionInfo.record
local postFrame = private.frame.content.result.confirmation.post
private.frame.content.result.cancelBtn:Disable()
private.frame.content.result.postBtn:Disable()
private.frame.content.result.bidBtn:Disable()
private.frame.content.result.buyoutBtn:Disable()
postFrame.postBtn:Enable()
postFrame.closeBtn:Enable()

local undercut = (TSMAPI:GetCustomPriceValue(TSM.db.global.postUndercut, auctionRecord.itemString) or 1)
if undercut > auctionRecord.itemBuyout then
    undercut = 1
end
if TSMAPI.Player:IsPlayer(auctionRecord.seller, true, true, true) then
    -- don't undercut ourselves
    undercut = 0
end
local auctionBuyout
if auctionRecord.isFake then
    auctionBuyout = TSMAPI:GetCustomPriceValue(TSM.db.global.normalPostPrice, auctionRecord.itemString) or 1000000
else
    auctionBuyout = auctionRecord.buyout - (undercut * auctionRecord.stackSize)
end
```

and I want to remove/replace this pattern

```
<tab here>if TSMAPI.Player:IsPlayer(auctionRecord.seller, true, true, true) then
    <tab><tab>-- don't undercut ourselves
    <tab><tab>undercut = 0
<tab here>end
```

via Powershell Script:

```
$text ="pattern_here!"
$content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText(path_to\test.lua")
(Get-Content 'path_to\test.lua')  -replace $test,"example" | Set-Content 'path_to\test.lua'
```

So the script does replace/remove operations perfectly , but only in one string.

What I have already tried: 
use $text.contains with

```
`r `n `t `s — Escape characters
```

and even if PowerShell reply is "true" is doesn't change anything

[this script from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403217/how-to-replace-multiple-strings-in-a-file-using-powershell) but it changes every string with "end", not only one which following next to "undercut = 0"

So, what am I join wrong? Already waste 3 H+ on this. Is it possible to use mask where first string should be start of $pattern and the first "end" will be the closing one?

Or I should covert all this strings to array?
Or...use concat? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it's a bit unusual but I waste almost 4 and 1/2 hour for this.
For all those who will read this, **use (Get-Content 'path_to\test.file' *-raw*)** if you are working with something different from usual .txt file, not matter "filetype" or "charset".

Answer (score 1):

One option:

```
$text = 
@'
   if TSMAPI.Player:IsPlayer(auctionRecord.seller, true, true, true) then
            -- don't undercut ourselves
            undercut = 0
    end
Keep this text
   if TSMAPI.Player:IsPlayer(auctionRecord.seller, true, true, true) then
            -- don't undercut ourselves
            undercut = 0
    end

'@

$replace_text = 
@'
   if TSMAPI.Player:IsPlayer(auctionRecord.seller, true, true, true) then
            -- don't undercut ourselves
            undercut = 0
    end
'@

$regex = "(?ms)$([regex]::Escape($replace_text))"

$text -replace $regex,"example"
```

The regex is built with `[regex]::Escape()`, using text that's simply copied and pasted from a sample of the data.  The `(?ms)` option makes it work with multi-line data

Comment: Thank you, I modify this one a bit, but it's doesn't work. Actually I already trying to find an answer for this problem via different forums. So let's skip the introduction and going to the "fun" part:

$regex = "(?ms)$([regex]::Escape($replace_text))"

$text -replace $regex,"example" | Set-Content 'path_to/test.lua'

I'm going to try this with masks:
\tif tsmapi(.|\r|\n|\t)*? - 
\tif tsmapi(.|\r|\n|\t)*?end

Original lua can be found here:  [Github](https://github.com/AlexZeDim/BlackOps_Model/blob/master/AuctionTab.lua)